# Count number of occurrence within time frame in R

Tags: r, datetime

This is a tough one for me. I have 3 months data (up to 1m obs) and I have 2 columns in my data.frame

```
Date_Time                Number
12/1/2015 12:00:01 AM    92222222
12/1/2015 12:00:29 AM    32211111
12/1/2015 12:00:41 AM    22333333
12/1/2015 12:00:43 AM    12222222
.....                    .....
12/1/2015 9:00:02 AM     92222222
12/2/2015 12:00:02 AM    32211111
```

How to count the occurrence/Frequency of each value in column "Number" within time frame of 24 hours.

the expected result of the above example

```
92222222 Freq: 2
32211111 Freq: 2
22333333 Freq: 1
12222222 Freq: 1
```

EDIT
time frame of 24 hours refer to interval of 24 hours. it doesn't mean from midnight to midnight. for example, if someone calls at 5 PM today, and call again at 3 PM next day, this should be counted as 2

Edit 2:
To be clearer, the objective of this analysis is to know the number of repeat calls in the call center for window period of 24 hours.

for example, customer called from contact number 01101111 on 1/Jan/2016 1:32:01 PM
& then called again on 1/Jan/2016 1:59:43 PM. and finally called next day 2/Jan/2016 12:21:02 PM
It's considered that the frequency of 0110111 is "3" because the number is repeated 3 times in less than 24 hours.

Comment: By a time frame of 24 hours you mean 24h from midnight to midnight, or a rolling/moving sum? If the latter, you will need to add some granularity to the time unless you want to store the Freq for every second. Edit: It looks like you want the latter, so you really need to group the numbers somehow, like every minute or hour and then use `RcppRoll::roll_sum` or `zoo::rollsum` functions.

Comment: Does your 24hours refer to calendar dates or moving window?

Comment: @M.D    No I mean 24 hours. not from midnight to midnight.

Comment: @chinsoon12 I don't refer to calendar dates, so I guess it'd be moving window

Comment: From my edit abowe: It looks like you want the latter, so you really need to group the numbers somehow, like every minute or hour and then use RcppRoll::roll_sum or zoo::rollsum functions.

Comment: Lapply on date time, within function add 24hours, use these start and end time to window the original df and perform stats?

Comment: @chinsoon12 Can you give me an example?

Comment: @M.D I thought it'd be easier than this. Can't R recognize that it's a time interval somehow?

Comment: @RayanSp it is not clear from your expected result what is the start time to consider. For instance, the value 32211111 appears only once if the start time is obtained from the first row.

Comment: @tfc there is no start time. it is an interval. pls read my edit.

Comment: Yeah agree with @tfc you will have 24*60*60 sets in your results

Comment: @chinsoon12 pls go ahead

Comment: @chinsoon12 then how do you suggest I do that? I am analyzing my repeated calls for a period of 24 hours.

Comment: @RayanSp your data frame has only the 24h period you are interested or the whole 3 months data (as described in the question)? If the latter, you will need to define a start time (without it there is no period) or use, as suggested previously, a roll function for each period possible within your data.

Comment: @tfc I asked a friend of mine (he was doing the same thing I am doing now) he said that it was complicated to do it in R, so he did through Perl... if it's not possible in R, I guess I will have to look for other solution like Perl. any thoughts?

Comment: @RayanSp the problem is not in the programming language adopted. It is just not clear what you want to compute (or if your expected result is wrong). Take a look at my previous comments and see if there is something wrong with my understanding of your problem.

Comment: @tfc I understand you now, you asked me what would be the starting point/time? it'd be defined differently for each record in the Number Column. for example `Date_Time                Number
12/1/2015 12:00:01 AM    92222222` the starting time would be `12/1/2015 12:00:01 AM` for the number `92222222`

Comment: @RayanSp what is not clear is if you are interested in only *one* period (considering the earliest call made by a number) or if all possible periods considering each call made by a number as the start of a *new* period. For example, the same number can call within 24 hours a different number of times in different weeks.

Comment: For your example: contact number 01101111, calls on 1/Jan/2016 1:32:01 PM, 1/Jan/2016 1:59:43 PM, 2/Jan/2016 12:21:02 PM. What do you expect to get when he calls again on 2/Jan/2016 1:33:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, for any number the start of the period is the earliest call from that number. 
Below is the commented code:

```
library(lubridate)                                                              
library(dplyr)          

calls <- structure(list(Date_Time = structure(1:6, .Label = c("12/1/2015 12:00:01 AM", 
"12/1/2015 12:00:29 AM", "12/1/2015 12:00:41 AM", "12/1/2015 12:00:43 AM", 
"12/1/2015 9:00:02 AM", "12/2/2015 12:00:02 AM"), class = "factor"), 
    Number = structure(c(4L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("12222222", 
    "22333333", "32211111", "92222222"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Date_Time", 
"Number"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


count_freq <- function(timestamps){                                             
    #Given all the ocurrences of calls from a number find the 
    #earliest one and count how many occur within 24 hours
    dtime <- sort(mdy_hms(timestamps))                                            
    start_time <- dtime[1]                                                        
    end_time <- start_time + hours(24)                                            
    sum(dtime >= start_time & dtime <= end_time)                                  
}


out <- group_by(calls, Number) %>% 
       summarise(freq = count_freq(Date_Time))
```

Comment: Thanks TFC, it's a proper approach, as you said, it doesn't matter the programming language adopted, what matters is the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach to output the freq of the number in each row for the 24 hrs, but most likely slower than tfc's.

```
df<-read.table(header = TRUE, sep=",", text="Date_Time,  Number
              12/1/2015 12:00:01 AM,    92222222
               12/1/2015 12:00:29 AM,    32211111
               12/1/2015 12:00:41 AM,    22333333
               12/1/2015 12:00:43 AM,    12222222
               12/1/2015 9:00:02 AM,     92222222
               12/2/2015 12:00:02 AM,    32211111")

df$Date_Time<-as.POSIXct(df$Date_Time, format="%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")

library(dplyr)
ncount<-function(x){
  target<-x[2]
  starttime<-as.POSIXct(x[1], format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  endtime<-starttime+ 24*60*60  #1 day later
  nrow(filter(df, Number==target & Date_Time>=starttime & Date_Time<=endtime))
}

df$freq<-apply(df, 1, function(x){ncount(x)} )
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, looks fine to me